# Calculation in jquery for keyup

Tags: jquery

I want to do simple calculation via jquery for inputs

if i write some value in first and second input it should display in fourth
if i write first, second, third and delete value from third (for example) i want it to clear second ( cuz they are for same purpose)
all of code which i tried is in link down below, any help is very much appreaciated :)

```js
$('#first, #second, #third, #fourth, #fifth').on('input', function() {
  var first = parseInt($('#first').val());
  var second = parseFloat($('#second').val());
  var third = parseInt($('#third').val());
  var fourth = parseFloat($('#fourth').val());
  var fifth = parseFloat($('#fifth').val());
});

function calc() {
  if (first.length > 0 && second.length > 0) {
    $('#third').val((first + second ? first + second : 0).toFixed(2));
  }
  if (second.length > 0 && third.length > 0) {
    $('#fourth').val((second + third ? second + third : 0).toFixed(2));
  }
  if (second.length > 0 && third.length > 0) {
    second.val('');
    third.val('');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type='text' name='first' id='first' value='' />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='text' name='second' id='second' value='' />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='text' name='third' id='third' value='' />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='text' name='fourth' id='fourth' value='' />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type='text' name='fifth' id='fifth' value='' />
  </li>
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZ92k/797/)

Comment: You misspelled `length` and `calc()` was not called?

Comment: Could you name the fields in a meaningful way, instead of first, second, etc? It would make it easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Yep gimme a min

Comment: Why do you have five input if you do nothing with the fifth? What is I write something in input fourth? What if I write somehting input one and third? I don't get what you want to achieve...if you want to calculate somehting, just use ONE input for the TOTAL and sum the total in all other input, I don't know?

Comment: it needs to be done in available fields not in one for all, because of calculations
for example : (price/100)*interest is to be written in payment or so

Comment: People are usually familiar with concepts of "price" and "interest", so unless your calculations are top-secret, I suggest naming the fields accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
<li>
    <input type='text' name='first' id='first' value='' />
</li>
<li>
  <input type='text' name='second' id='second' value='' />
</li>
<li>
  <input type='text' name='third' id='third' value='' />
</li>
<li>
  <input type='text' name='fourth' id='fourth' value='' />
</li>
<li>
  <input type='text' name='fifth' id='fifth' value='' />
</li>
<li>
  <input type='button' name='sixth' id='sixth' value='Calculate' />
</li>
</ul>
```

This jquery will calculate the fields with the button click.

```
 $('#sixth').click( function() {
        var number = Number($('#first').val()) + Number($('#second').val()) +  Number($('#third').val())
        $('#fourth').val(number);

});
```

Hope this gets you closer to what you need.